# If statement on PHP (inserting data)

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have to register a costumer and/or a manager into the database. I just have one form for the information, the only difference is the ID number (valid for managers). The costumers should leave this form blank. I was trying to save the data just using an `if` statement (If it is blank, save the information in `costumer` table. If it is not, save in `manager`). I have not seen this on my classes so I am not sure if it is possible.

Is it possible to use an `if` statement to insert data? What I mean is, I have two different tables but just one form (one of the forms will make the difference for which table the data will be saved.

The data in the `manager` table is ok, but when I try to insert data into `costumer` it is not working. I am not sure that I can use this.

```
if($_SESSION['id'] != null){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO manager (id,magname,maglname,maguser,magpass) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
  $sth = $DBH->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(3, $_SESSION['secondname'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(4, $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(5, $_SESSION['password'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->execute();
}

if(empty($_SESSION['id']){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO costumer (fisrtname,lastname,username,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
  $sth = $DBH->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['lastname'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(3, $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(4, $_SESSION['password'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? Does your insert throw error or it doesnt insert anything?

Comment: Use `isset()` and `empty()` instead, and/or an `else{...}`

Comment: FYI: `== null` does not just check if a variable is `NULL`, as it's [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). It also checks if the variable is `FALSE`, `0`, an empty array or an empty string.

Comment: Actually it is not producing any error, it is just not saving on my database when the SESSION['id'] is empty.

Comment: You should show us your full or more code then. Plus, make sure your column allows for NULLs. Plus, you did start the session, and is inside all pages using sessions?

Comment: ^ Hi Quelms. Please edit this information into your question, and then delete the comments. As you can see, code does not render very well in comments.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it directly through following code

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `manager`..."
   else
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `customer`..."
```

Answer (score 0):

or something like this

```
   if(!empty($_SESSION['id']))
          {  $sql = "INSERT INTO `manager`..."}
   else
          {  $sql = "INSERT INTO `customer`..."}
```